# 'No matching function to call swap(partecipante&, partecipante&)' error

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to call the std function 'random_shuffle' in c++, but when i try to call it it gives me this compile- time error

[image]

the calling is this:

```
std::random_shuffle ( partecipanti.begin(), partecipanti.end() );
```

where *'partecipanti'* is std::vector and *'partecipante'* is this class:

```
class partecipante{
private:
    const std::string nome;
    unsigned int ELO;
    const bool reale;
public:
    partecipante(std::string n="",unsigned int e=0, bool r=true);
    operator bool() const;
    bool operator==(const partecipante&) const;


    //....other methods...

};
```

i have also included vector,algorithm and random from STL.
What can I do then?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ValueSwappable

Comment: According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), that call might be using a deprecated signature for random_shuffle.

Comment: Are you trying to use `std::swap`? That won't work for `const` members.